# How to go about separating data in a .csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv, split

I have a .csv file that includes a long line of data. The data looks something along the lines of:

```
Name,Gender,Age John Smith,M,23 Ashley Jones,F,18 James Smith Johns,M,20
```

My end goal is to separate all of the data so I can put them into rows. My intended result would be:

```
['Name','Gender','Age','John Smith','M','23','Ashley Jones','F','18','James Smith Jones','M','20']
```

However, using something like:

```
line = line.split(",")
line = line.split(" ")
```

Will not work as it will separate them at the , or space and there will be values like:

```
'Age John Smith' or 'Age','John','Smith'
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: If you really want to split the part `18 James Smith Johns` into two values `18` and `James Smith Johns`, then you probably need some sort of additional logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split at `,` first and then iterate over that list and split at each item at whitespaces. If after splitting at whitespaces number of items returned are more than 1 then return the first item and rest of the items separately otherwise simply return the first item.

```
import csv
def solve(row):
    for item in row:
        spl = item.split(None, 1)
        if len(spl) > 1:
            yield spl[0]
            yield spl[1]           
        else:
            yield spl[0]
...             
with open('abc1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:      
        print list(solve(row))
...         
['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'John Smith', 'M', '23', 'Ashley Jones', 'F', '18', 'James Smith Johns', 'M', '20']
```

Comment: Nice answer. One thought though: You can use `spl = item.split(None, 1)` (maxsplit = 1). So you don't have to join the elements afterwards.

Comment: Not really a proper csv file as it's all one big row (`for row in reader` only iterates once).  So in this case the `csv.reader` is just verbose way of splitting by a comma.  Might as well do `list(solve(f.read().split(',')))`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using a regular expression:

```
re.compile("([^,]+),([^,]+),(\d+|Age)\s+").findall("Name,Gender,Age John Smith,M,23 Ashley Jones,F,18 James Smith Johns,M,20")
```

The result for this will be:

```
[('Name', 'Gender', 'Age'), ('John Smith', 'M', '23'), ('Ashley Jones', 'F', '18')]
```

Comment: No need to compile a single-use regular expression--just use the top level `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1):

There are nice `re`-solutions, but I just wanted to add this non-regex solution:

```
>>> s = "John Smith,M,23 Ashley Jones,F,18 James Smith Johns,M,20"
>>> sum((item.split(None, 1) for item in s.split(',')), list())
['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'John Smith', 'M', '23', 'Ashley Jones', 'F', '18', 'James Smith Johns', 'M', '20']
```

Instead of `sum`, you can also use `itertools.chain`. But in the end, it does not seem to be  shorter at all.

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[item.split(None, 1) for item in s.split(',')]))
```

or better

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(item.split(None, 1) for item in s.split(',')))
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski +1 You are right, this is what I meant. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression way. :-)

```
>>> s = "John Smith,M,23 Ashley Jones,F,18 James Smith Johns,M,20" #Note: no title here.
>>> [(x.group(1), x.group(3), x.group(4)) for x in re.finditer(r"(\S+( \S+)),(\S),(\d+)",s)]
[('John Smith', 'M', '23'), ('Ashley Jones', 'F', '18'), ('Smith Johns', 'M', '20')]
```

Note that I have removed the title (first line), you'll need to modify the regexp accordingly, or modify the input string.

Answer (score -1):

As I see in example line will be `line = line.split(",")` enoght. Maybe I didn't get something?

Comment: Some values are separated by spaces. Read the end of his post.